# why we get only one unique straight line in a,b co ordinates for a point given in x,y co-ordinates?

Tags: math, image-processing, line, coordinates, hough-transform

If there is a point that is given in x,y co-ordinate, we can pass infinite number of straight lines from it by varying slope a and intercept b.
But when we fix our x and y and vary our a and b in a,b co-ordinate we get a single unique line. Why?
I found this annoying while studying Hough transform.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you want to ask....but yes this may clear things a bit. When you fix a point you can make infinite lines pass through it.This is obvious. Now you fix the a,b as co-ordinates that is you have fixed for one particular case the slope and the y-intercept both.

Now note that the slope can vary between a definite range. If you consider the argument, it will vary from 0 degrees to 180 degrees. now out of the infinite lines having different slopes that pass through a point (in this case the point on the y-axis i.e. the y-intercept of your line) you are essentially selecting one line in particular having a specific slope. now only one such line is possible.

I hope this answers your question...